# Cannot deserialize instance of currency from VALUE_STRING value 1,9459.1650 or request may be missing a required field

Tags: community, composite

When using Salesforce composite getting this error. How to resolve this?

Cannot deserialize instance of currency from VALUE_STRING value 1,9459.1650 or request may be missing a required field

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you need to remove the `,` from that string. This might be difficult to do, however, given that all the other commas are needed. You could chop the string up by looking for the JSON name - say you know it's called 'cost' ... find from this for eg {cost: 1,9459.1560, someothervalue: "something"} - look for 'cost' and replace the FIRST instance of a comma after that. Make sense?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], and take the [tour]. In order for us to properly help you, we need more information. Please describe exactly what you're trying to do, and provide any relevant code. This will help us narrow down an appropriate solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to remove the `,` from that string. This might be difficult to do, however, given that all the other commas are needed.

You could chop the string up by looking for the JSON name - say you know it's called 'cost' ... find from this for eg

```
{cost: 1,9459.1560, someothervalue: "something", more: "something else"}`
```

- look for 'cost' and replace the FIRST instance of a comma after that.

Or split on `,`

You would get an array like this:

```
['cost: 1']
['9459.1560']
['someothervalue: "something"']
['more: "something else"']
```

From here you can scan through the array (backwards) and find any object with no `:`
It clearly belongs to the previous name value pair.

eg:

```
String[] fixedJSONArray = new String[]{};
for(Integer i = badJSONArray.length -1, i > -1, i--){
  String nameVal = badJSONArray[i];
  if (nameVal.contains(':')){
    fixedJSONArray.push(nameVal);
  }
  else {
    fixedJSONArray.push(badJSONArray[i-1] + nameVal);
  }
}
String fixedJSON = '{' + String.join(fixedJSONArray,',') + '}';
```

Comment: How do you know it's JSON? What if it's CSV? Or something else? I'm just curious.

Comment: Hahah it's always JSON! Anyway, same principle applies.

Comment: Oh and composite - that's a composite http - which is json

Comment: Thanks it worked :-)

Comment: Btw ... this could break if there are more commas etc in the number. For that you will need a fancier algorithm - maybe something recursive.